# Error when building Android App

Tags: android

I am trying to build my project in android studio which always work fine, but today it gave me the following error:

```
Error:(39, 2) Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> ...........................\app\src\main\res\values\strings.xml:39:2: Error:
The type of "string" element must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</ string>".
```

Here is full XML file:

```
<string name="app_name">CDU</string>
<string name="contact_email" translatable="false">test@ysrsd.com/string>
<string name="gcm_key">000000000</string>
<string name="map_key" translatable="false">000000000</string>
<string name="euro">&#8364;</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="gallery">Gallery</string>
<string name="about_us">About us</string>
<string name="address_restaurant">Address</string>
<string name="error_msg">Connection can\'t be established</string>
<string name="about_restaurant">About CDU/string>
<string name="opening_time">Opening Times</string>
<string name="call_restaurant">Call us for enquiry</string>
<string name="send_message">Send message to us</string>
<string name="no_notifications">We don\'t have any notifications yet.</string>
<string name="how_to_get_there">How to get there</string>
<string name="start_navigation">Start navigation to the center</string>
<string name="locate_us">Locate Us</string>
<string name="last_notification">Last Notification</string>
<string name="crash_toast_text">App stopped working. Please help us fix this by sending us error data.</string>
<string name="contact_us">Contact Us</string>
<string name="name">Your name</string>
<string name="contact">Your contact number</string>
<string name="email">Your email address</string>
<string name="message">Tell us about your concern</string>
<string name="name_contact_validation">Name and contact number are necessary</string>
<string name="email_validation">Email address is not valid</string>
<string name="email_feedback">Feedback</string>
<string name="no_internet">No Network!</string>
<string name="no_internet_msg">Please make sure that you are connected to internet</string>
<string name="not_able_to_connect">We\'re facing problem connecting to server, please retry</string>
<string name="website">Reservas</string>
<string name="website_url" translatable="false">http://www.google.es</string>
```

Can someone help me fix this issue, thanks.

Comment: Can you post the entire XML file?  There's a chance the error isn't actually on that line, but on a previous one because it's a parsing issue.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have edited original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second line and 11th line are currently missing correct closing tags (missing "<")

```
<string name="contact_email" translatable="false">test@ysrsd.com/string>
...
<string name="about_restaurant">About CDU/string>
```

Change it to the following:

```
<string name="contact_email" translatable="false">test@ysrsd.com</string>
...
<string name="about_restaurant">About CDU</string>
```

Comment: @Holmes what do you mean by that?

Comment: Also for `about_restaurant `

Comment: @Spainman2015 glad it was just a simple parsing issue, and not a larger Android Studio compiling issue!

Answer (score -1):

try using:

```
<string name="website_url" translatable="false">"http://www.google.es"</string>
```

Comment: the issue isn't actually with that line - in their posted XML, the second line is missing a correct closing tag